# Дано квадратную матрицу А порядка n. Нужно построить матрицу B, чтобы каждый её элемент

Tags: c++, массивы, матрицы

был равен наибольшему из элементов матрицы А, которые находятся в той же строчке и в том же столбике, что иискомый элемент. Я написала программу, которая ищет максимальные элементы в столбиках и строчках матрицы А. Теперь, по идее, нужно ещё раз найти максимальные элементы в тех двух столбиках, но как это сделать? И как заполнить этими элементами матрицу В? Я вообще в ту сторону думаю?))

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Order of matrix A is " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cout << endl;
    int** A = new int* [n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        A[i] = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            A[i][j] = rand() % 100;
            cout << setw(3) << A[i][j] << " ";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
    int max;
    int** B = new int* [n];
    max = A[0][0];

    for (int c = 0; c < n; c++)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < n; a++)
        {
            if (max < A[c][a]) max = A[c][a];
        }

        cout << max << endl;
        max = 0;
    }

    cout << endl;

    for (int a = 0; a < n; a++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < n; c++)
        {
            if (max < A[c][a]) max = A[c][a];
        }

        cout << max << endl;
        max = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Заведите два массива: один - размером в строку матрицы А, другой - размером в столбец матрицы А. Заполните эти массивы максимальными значениями в столбцах и строках соответственно. Для нахождения значений элементов матрицы Б, выбирайте большее из двух чисел, находящихся по соответствующим индексам тех двух массивов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делаем два массива (вектора, ...) - в одном собираем максимальные значения строк, в другом - столбцов. Скажем, это `r[]` и `c[]`. Тогда `B[i][j]` - это максимум из `r[i]` и `c[j]`.

Все просто :)

*По-моему, так (с) Пух*

**Update** Готовое решение:

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Order of matrix A: ";
    cin >> n;
    int** A = new int* [n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        A[i] = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            A[i][j] = rand() % 100;
            cout << setw(3) << A[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    int** B = new int* [n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        B[i] = new int[n];

    int * r = new int[n];
    int * c = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        r[i] = c[i] = INT_MIN;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (A[i][j] > r[i]) r[i] = A[i][j];
            if (A[i][j] > c[j]) c[j] = A[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            B[i][j] = (r[i] > c[j]) ? r[i] : c[j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cout << setw(3) << B[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;


    delete[] r;
    delete[] c;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        delete[] A[i];
        delete[] B[i];
    }
    delete[] A;
    delete[] B;

}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!  Но проблема в том, что у меня не получается собрать эти максимальные элементы в два массива. Я не могу понять, какие изменения нужно внести в мой цикл, чтобы это сделать. (Извините, что немножко туплю: я просто только 1-й семестр изучаю С++ :D)

Comment: Ну, смотрите обновленный ответ... Если устроит - пометьте как принятый, и спокойной ночи :)

Comment: Огромное спасибо! И вам спокойной ночи) А как отметить ваш ответ?

Comment: Слева от ответа есть "птичка", которую нажимают, если ответ является ответом на вопрос, и два треугольника - для мнения о полезности/вредности ответа. Треугольники мжет нажимать каждый, "птицу" - только автор вопроса.